# Using node red to implement a chat bot into http, how can I analyse the tone of the input using the bluemix tone analyser in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, node-red

I have been trying to create a chat bot that asks psychological questions to analyse how a person is feeling. I have made a chat bot in Bluemix and implemented that into node red with the help of this tutorial: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-red-labs/tree/master/basic_examples/conversation
So my flow is very similar, with the addition being that I have added a tone analyser and connected it at the same part as the conversation.
My main problem is that I can't seem to access the values from the tone analyser in the html template through dot notation, but the response debug is showing that the input is definitely being analysed.
how can I adapt the flow or the AJAX code so that the template will allow for the tone analyser values to be accessed. (The code that is commented out is my attempt at sorting my issue, although I'm not particularly clued up on AJAX so it's a little messy).

[image: Flow image]

```
<html>   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>       My BOT    </title>    <link rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />   </head>   <body>

<div class="container">
  <div id="no-script"class="bg-info">
    This application needs JavaScript enabled in your browser!
  </div>
  <div id="id_contextdump"></div>

  <h1>My BOT</h1>
  <div id=id_botchathistory>      </div>

  <div>
      <form>
        <label for="id_chattext">Your Input: </label>
        <input type="text" name="chattext" id="id_chattext">
        <br/><br/>
      </form>
      <button onclick="javascript:onChatClick()">Send</button>    </div>
</div>
<div id="id_tone">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Tone</th>
            <th>Score</th>
        </tr>
        {{#response.document_tone.tone_categories.0.tones}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{tone_id}}</td>
            <td>{{score}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/response.document_tone.tone_categories.0.tones}}
    </thead>
</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
      javascriptCheck();
        $('#id_contextdump').hide();
  });

  // if javascript is enabled on the browser then can
  // remove the warning message
  function javascriptCheck() {
    $('#no-script').remove();
  }

  function createNewDiv(who, message) {
    var txt = who + ' : ' + message;
    return $('<div></div>').text(txt);
  }

  function chat(person, txt) {
    $('#id_botchathistory').append(createNewDiv(person, txt));
  }    
   //      function updateTone(){ //          $('#id_tone').append(createNewDiv(response.document_tone.tone_categories.0.tones)) //      }

  function processOK(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.botresponse.messageout);
    console.log(response.botresponse.messageout.output.text);
    console.log(response.botresponse.messageout.context);
    chat('Bot', response.botresponse.messageout.output.text);
    $('#id_contextdump').data('convContext', response.botresponse.messageout.context);
  }

  function processNotOK() {
    chat('Error', 'Error whilst attempting to talk to Bot');
  }

  function invokeAjax(message) {
    var contextdata = $('#id_contextdump').data('convContext');
    console.log('checking stashed context data');
    console.log(contextdata);


    //var ajaxData = "msgdata=" + message;
    var ajaxData = {};
    ajaxData.msgdata = message;
    if (contextdata) {
      ajaxData.context = contextdata;    
    } //        var tone = { //            document: {}, //            sentence: {} //        };
     //        tone.document = getTones(data.document_tone);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'botchat',
      data: ajaxData,
      success: processOK,
      error: processNotOK
    });
  }

  // User has entered some text.
  function onChatClick() {
    var txt = $('#id_chattext').val();
    chat('You', txt);
    invokeAjax(txt); //        updateTone();
  }
   //      var tone_analyser = watson.tone_analyzer({ //        username: 'e7cc7d78-d63f-42a9-ac1b-c900bbee33a4', //        password: '57NyBACkO5s3', //        version: 'v3', //        version_date: '2016-05-19' //    });
   //      window.setInterval("refreshDiv()", 500); //      function refreshDiv(){ //          tone_analyser= tone_analyser; //    }

</script>   </body> </html>
```

In:

```
_// stash away incoming data_
msg.mydata = {};
msg.mydata.messagein = msg.req.body.msgdata;
msg.payload = msg.mydata.messagein;

msg.params = { "context": msg.req.body.context};

return msg;
```

Out:

```
msg.mydata.messageout = msg.payload;

msg.payload = {};
msg.payload.botresponse = msg.mydata;

return msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be because you have forked the flow after the `in` function node. This won't work unless the `out` function node is only outputting after it has received 2 input messages.

When you fork a flow it it run sequentially, not in parallel, this is due to the fact that NodeJS is totally single threaded. This means that only the results from the `Art Attack` node will be returned to the http-out node and back to your page.

Without knowing exactly what is in the `out` function node it's not possible to say how to fix this.

Comment: Ah right! That makes sense. If that's the case, then I will give you the in and out code!

Comment: Look at the options on the `join` node, insert it before the `out` function node, then edit the `out` function to work with the array.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to Node Red, so after connecting the join node and telling it to create an array, how do I access that array in the out function to work with it? As in what is that new array called?